# How to skip building twice when using docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, sonarqube

In our project we are using Docker + AKS, and as part of the build it produces Docker images. Also we have SonarQube analysis in place.

Currently our build steps involve NuGet restoration, build the .csproj (we are using a .Net application), test, send the results to SonarQube and once the SonarQube is successful, build the docker image.

Inside the Dockerfile we are again restoring and building the application. Is there a way we can skip this multiple build? I know that we can use cmd to run the unit tests but its doesn't help in this situation. Is there any best practise to follow to cut down the build time?

**Update**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /source
COPY {sourcedetails}
COPY ["NuGet.config", "src/"]
{Restoration}
RUN rm "src/NuGet.config"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/source/src/API"
RUN dotnet build "API.csproj" -c Release

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /source/src/API
RUN dotnet publish "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish --self-contained false


FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup
USER appuser
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]
```

The other pieces are happening at azure devops

Comment: Please, post the contents of your Dockerfile. A sensible ordering of the instructions in your Dockerfile plus a multi-stage build (https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) can improve the Docker cache usage (https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/) and thus your build time, but it's impossible to give you a better answer witout seeing the actual Dockerfile

Comment: added dockerfile, steps where the other set of restoration, build, test and sonar are happening as indivudial tasks as part of the azure devops pipeline not inside docker file. I want to move tests, sending it to sonar inside dockerfile if possible.

Comment: Did you already find a solution? I am facing the same dilemma. This article: https://colinsalmcorner.com/net-core-multi-stage-dockerfile-with-test-and-code-coverage-in-azure-pipelines/ describes exactly your problem but suggests doing sonar and tests from the Docker instead, it has some positive aspects as well.

Comment: one good source I found is this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A73n-hhsm4I&t=1551s (it shows the other way around - build outside of the docker)

Comment: I dont find anything except running these inside docker file itself. I tried to do the same running tests and sonar inside docker. but, it requires more changes then anticipated, currently we parked it. but I will check this video.